# split character object, problems with {

Tags: r

I need to split a character object called C which looks like:

```
"{TV}{Property}{Furniture}{Car or Van}{Phone}{Computer or Tablet}{Holiday}{None of the above}"
```

First, I have tried to do use split:

```
D<-strsplit(C[1], split = "}")
```

It works and it returns me:

```
[1] "{TV"                 "{Property"           "{Furniture"          "{Car or Van"         "{Phone"              "{Computer or Tablet" "{Holiday"           
[8] "{None of the above"
```

But I want to get rid of the other "{". When I try to do it though R gets "confused" with the curly bracket

```
E<-unlist(strsplit(D, split="{")
Error in strsplit(D[[1]], split = "{") : invalid regular expression '{', reason 'Missing '}''
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution to clean your data :

```
gsub("[{}]","",strsplit(C,"\\}\\{")[[1]])

[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"          "Car or Van"        
[5] "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet" "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either `escape` ie.  (`\\{|\\}`) or use `[{}]`

```
 D <- strsplit(C, "[{}]")[[1]]
 D[nzchar(D)]
 #[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
 #[4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
 #[7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Or

```
  strsplit(C, "\\{|}\\{|}")[[1]][-1]
  #[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
  #[4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
  #[7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Or other options are

```
  regmatches(C,gregexpr("[^{}]+", C))[[1]]
  #[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
  #[4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
  #[7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Or

```
  library(stringr)
  str_extract_all(C, '[^{}]+')[[1]]
  #[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
  #[4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
  #[7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Or

```
  library(stringi)
  stri_extract_all_regex(C, '[^{}]+')[[1]]
  #[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
  #[4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
  #[7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Or

```
  library(qdap)
  unname(bracketXtract(C, 'curly'))
  #[1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
  #[4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
  #[7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `strsplit` only, you could do

```
strsplit(x, "[{}]+")[[1]][-1]
# [1] "TV"                 "Property"           "Furniture"         
# [4] "Car or Van"         "Phone"              "Computer or Tablet"
# [7] "Holiday"            "None of the above"
```

Since the algorithm of `strsplit` *adds the string to the left of the match to the output then removes the match and all to the left of it*, and your string begins with the character we're splitting on, we just need to remove the first element of the result (shown by `[-1]`).